# Finite Quantum Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

I want to start by saying i promise i'm not stupid but this has me stumped for more than a week now. I have to find the number of Quantum states in the conduction band. Easy enough $V_0 = \Delta{Ec}= 0.67\Delta{Eg}=250.6$ meV, $m_w=m_{e*}=0.0667m_0$ for GaAs. and N is the number of Quantum states in the well $(L=10nm)$

$$\sqrt{2m_wV_0}\left(\frac{L}{2\hbar}\right)<N\frac{\pi}2$$

So now for the stumped part. Am I using the wrong values for $m_o$ and $\hbar$? I've used $m_0=9.11 \cdot 10^{-31}$ kg and $\hbar=6.582 \cdot 10^{-16}$ eV.s. Heck I've even used and all other units for these two that I can find but I'm just not getting the right answer. ($N=3.3$ if anyone cares).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be that you used eV as a scale for energy, but you also used kg as a unit of mass, which means you're mixing different units and there should be a conversion factor somewhere ($1$ eV $\approx 1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ J $= 1.6 \times 10^{-19} \, \mathrm{kg \cdot m^2 \cdot s^{-2}}$).

By instead using only SI units $V_0 = 250.6 \, \mathrm{meV} \approx 4.01 \times 10^{-20} \, \mathrm{J}$ and $\hbar \approx 1.05 \times 10^{-34} \, \mathrm{J \cdot s}$, I find $N = 2.12$.

Note that if I use $V_0 = 0.67 E_g = 0.67 \times 1.424 \, \mathrm{eV} = 954 \, \mathrm{meV}$ instead, as suggested in the picture, I find something different ($N = 4. 12$).

Does that make sense? I suggest you double check the values of $m_w$ and $V_0$ that are given to you, and convert everything to SI units if needed.