# Eigen-energy in Finite Quantum Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

So I'm a beginner at quantum mechanics and I'm learning about finite quantum wells. I've been stuck on an example on how to find Eigen-energies in conduction and valence bands of the quantum well shown below.

[image]

I have learned only the graphical way to find eigen-energies of this system. Though I understand the graphical approach I'm not sure how to actually use it while solving an example. Should I plot this graph in a software, find the values of x and y and then use x=(kL/2),

[image]

to find Eigen energies? The thing is my teacher never mentioned that we may have to use a software for this so I'm not sure if I'm even allowed to. Any help to find Eigen energies of C1, HH1 and LH1 (from first figure) would be appreciated. Please know that this is an example from "Physics of Photonics Devices; Chapter 3" so I already know the answer I'm just trying to understand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611846/2451

Answer (score 0):

In problems like those you are left with Transcendental Equations were your only alternative to ACTUALLY solve them is to resort to a computacional approach. In terms of the physics of the problem, usually, the graphical approach gives you plenty (if not all) of the information you need to understand them.

It goes from problem to problem, but in some of them you can apply some approximations to reduce the transcendental equation to a 'solvable' one. (as in the Dielectric Slab Waveguide or the Finite Quantum Well).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how such equations can be reduced for a finite quantum well?

Comment: The slab waveguide and finite quantum well share similarities on the transcendental equations, if you assume k is small (fundamental mode) the transcendental equation can be solved on first order

Comment: Yeah this is a first order equation. k is dependent on E which is what I need to find out and also k is in tangent part of the equation too so I'm having difficulty solving this without graphing.